# Where to find the mod_cgi.c script

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, cgi, ulimit

Where is the mod_cgi.c script, or where are all the modules in the apache software?

I have a problem with the `RLimitNProc` settings on my server, because this settings don't work properly. I've found in the deep of the internet that there is a bug in the apache 2.2 software, exactly in `mod_cgi.c` script, but I can't find that script wether on the server nor on a fresh downloaded apache 2.2. software.

I have just found the `mod_cgi.so` file, but the `.so` files are not intended to being changed...

I'm running CentOS 5.8

Thanks in advance.
Regards, John.

Answer (score 1):

The file `mod_cgi.c` isn't a script, it's a C source file. You can find the CentOS 5.8 version in the [SRPM](http://vault.centos.org/5.8/updates/SRPMS/httpd-2.2.3-65.el5.centos.3.src.rpm).

Answer (score 1):

mod_cgi.c is not a script. It is C source code. You would need to download the source code, not the compiled software.

Changing the source code for such a complex system is something you probably shouldn't do unless you are very familiar with C indeed. I'd strongly suggest that you look for a version of apache that doesn't have the bug in question; if none exists, wait a little. Also, many bugs have workarounds that can be made in the server configuration to disable the exploit. If you were to add information about the bug, we might be able to help you.

Comment: thanks. the question with my problem is [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/489665/ulimit-u-could-be-exceeded-by-some-user?noredirect=1#comment546860_489665), and i found [this](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54133) "solution" (don't know if it's a solution for **my** problem)

Comment: On the bug report page, it says "fixed in 2.4.4". So upgrading to that version should fix your problem. If it doesn't, you can download the SRPM as Iain suggested, patch the file yourself with the patch from the Apache page, and then compile it.

Comment: yes, thanks. i will prefer to update to 2.4.4, but i found it interesting for myself to check if my "mod_cgi.c" is corrupted or not :) regards

Comment: Looking at source code is always interesting :-)

Comment: @JennyD: aye, and the source code for the C5.8 version of mod_cgi.c doesn't have the code listed in the OPs 'solution'.

Comment: @lain: maybe i'm looking wrong, but i'm sure it does! looking at "modules/generators/mod_cgi.c" lines 426 to 460 are exactly the wrong lines of code as stated in the "bug report" at my question :)